Airflow sensor task, run for 3 days straight waiting for file to get added to GCS bucket
I have a DAG that currently checks a GCS bucket for a specific file that comes once a month. The problem I have is that his file will come on the 6th "Working day" of the month, which could mean it could be the 6th, 7th, 8th, even 9th depending on holidays/weekends. I need to have my sensor task that searches the bucket look at the bucket for a given day range, so schedule the DAG to start on the 6th and the sensor task will run until the 9th waiting for a file, if time goes passes the 9th then the DAG fails.
I was looking in just giving the specific task
# check if daily date file is available
    sensor_task = GCSObjectsWithPrefixExistenceSensor(
        task_id=f"detect_feed_file",
        bucket=LANDING_BUCKET,
        prefix=PREFIX,
        timeout=60,
    )

A timeout of timeout=3 * 24 * 60 * 60 instead of just 60 seconds. This being 3 days worth of seconds. Is this the most efficient method to go about this however? I was reading about poke_intervals as well, can this be used alongside the timeout as well? Only checking the bucket every hour, for the 3 days the sensor runs?
Can someone help me modify this task to achieve what im trying to get at, thank you

Have a look at BaseSensorOperator, and I would advice you to use reschedule mode.

Could use timetables and create a custom schedule https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/timetable.html

Yes, you are recommended to poke_interval along with timeout. Also, consider using the sensor's reschedule mode to efficiently utilize worker slots. Whenever possible, use Deferrable Operators.
Refer: https://www.astronomer.io/docs/learn/what-is-a-sensor#sensor-best-practices
